# SQL Server Stored Procedure Syntax Error on Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am unsure where I am making a mistake on the syntax next to the value part of the insert statements. What is the proper way to construct this stored procedure?

What I am looking to do is create a stored procedure that inserts data into multiple tables and also runs a check to see if some of the data already exists. if it does then it runs an update on a different table. if not then it inserts the data into a different table.

I hope that clarifies what I am trying to do.

```
create procedure usp_addQuickContacts
    @Email char(1000),
    @employeeName Char(50),
    @contactDetails char(250),
    @contactType char(50)
as
Begin
    Create Table #Temp
    (     
         Email char(1000),
         employeeName Char(50),
         contactDetails char(250),
         contactType char(50)
    )
End
Begin
    Insert into #Temp (Email, employeeName, contactDetails, contactType)
    Values (@Email, @employeeName, @contactDetails, @contactType)
End
Begin
    If Not exists (select ContactType from ContactType
                   where ContactType.ContactType = @contactType)
    Begin
        Insert into ContactType(ContactType)
        Value (@contactType)
    End
    Else
        If exists (Select * From ContactType
                   Inner Join #Temp On ContactType.ContactType = #Temp.ContactType)
        Begin
            Update StudentContacts
            Set StudentContacts.ContactTypeID = ContactType.ContactTypeID
            From ContactType
            Where StudentContacts.ContactTypeID is null
        End
End
Begin
    Insert into StudentInformation (Email)
    Value (@Email)
End
Begin
    Insert into Employees(EmployeeName)
    Value (@employeeName)
End
Begin
    Insert into StudentContacts(ContactDetails)
    Value (@contactDetails)
End
go
```

Comment: Which  error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `value` use `Values`

```
Insert into StudentContacts(ContactDetails)
    Values (@contactDetails)
```